# POSTing JSON document to an IBM Cloudant database using jQuery

Tags: jquery, api, post, cloudant

This maybe very basic to some out there(hopefully) but Ive signed up with IBM bluemix and Im trying to POST documents to a Cloudant database merely using jQuery. The database is called historysites and the documents have indexs called name, era and access. Its not working for me and im getting the error alert. Any experts on CLoudant with patience for a beginner would be appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <link href="css/history.css" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>
     <body> 

      <div id="holder">

       <div id="heading"><h1 class="mainTitle">The Historical Site Exchange</h1>               </div>
<div class="form-holder">
<h4 class="form-heading">Enter Your Historical Site to Match the List</h4><br />
<div class="insert-holder">

        <form>
        <div class="inserts">Name: <input type="text" id="one" style="width:80%;" /></div>
        <div class="inserts">Era: <input type="text" id="two" style="width:80%;" /></div>
        <div class="inserts">Access: <input type="text" id="three" style="width:80%;" /></div>

        <div class="inserts"><button id="trialer">Add Site</button></div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var one=$('#one').val();
    var two=$('#two').val();
    var three=$('#three').val();

    $("#trialer").on('click', function(){
        var requester={ name:one, era:two, access:three}
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "https://fba531c7-0a0e-437e-b1e3-962c3968f18e-bluemix:846d41093464a968dd6b12310cb78e2651cbf91bfd069c69d0e1b18447311213@fba531c7-0a0e-437e-b1e3-962c3968f18e-bluemix.cloudant.com/historysites",
            data: requester,
            success: function(ok){
                alert('uploaded');
            },
            error: function(nope){
                alert('afraid not');
            }

    });




    });
});


</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're connecting to your Cloudant databse on the server side. There are few ways to connect to your database. 
One way to do it is to connect to your cloudant database using the following code. Make sure you write this code in the file containing your routes or you place it in a separate file and export the db to your routes file:

```
var cloudant  = require('cloudant')("MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@MYACCOUNT.cloudant.com");
console.log("logged into cloudant");

db = cloudant.db.use("Name_of_database");
```

Now you can access documents in your databse using db.insert, db.destroy, etc..

Another way to do it is to create and object with all of your database access information and you can send requests using that.

```
  var options = {
    hostname: "ACCOUNT.cloudant.com",
    path: "/DB_NAME/DOCUMENT_ID",
    method: 'GET',
    auth: "USERNAME" +":" + "PASSWORD"
  }

 request.get(options, function(err,body) {...});
```

The variables you want to add in "options" varies based on your request. For example you may or may not want to add a header, you may need to remove the document id, etc.. Look at the documentation at github.com/request/request or ask me on here if you have any more questions about this method. Best of luck.

Comment: sorry under options you want to change hostname to url

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't talk to the database directly from client side JavaScript code. Anyone can just see your database credentials by looking at the source in the browser.

Also, you didn't tell us what error you were getting, but it's likely the browser restricting cross domain xhr calls (security restriction). Open the developer console in your browser and look at the console tab. Browsers don't by default allow JavaScript to POST to another domain unless the url you are calling implemented CORS and white listed your domain.

You can call the database from server side code, like php, node, servlet, etc

Comment: There are no errors in the developer console. My own error handler(an alert) appears. I was told that api's could connect directly to Cloudant noSQL databases, perhaps I was misinformed or misunderstood them

Comment: To help us understand a bit further on ajax error can you alert the error as well? Maybe something like this:  

error: function(jqXHR, textstatus, errorThrown) {
  alert('text status ' + textstatus + ', err ' + errorThrown);
 }